# How to convert INTERSECT from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I wrote a query to SQLite that works but now I have to use it in MySQL but I can't convert INTERSECT

The query is:

```
SELECT year FROM Movie,Rating 
WHERE Movie.mID=Rating.mID AND (stars='4' OR stars='5') 

INTERSECT 

SELECT year FROM Movie,Rating WHERE Movie.mID=Rating.mID AND (stars='4' OR stars='5') 

ORDER BY year ASC
```

I tried using INNER JOIN that LEFT JOIN but I don't get the correct result. Can I have some suggestions?

Comment: Am I missing something? Both SELECT statements look identical to me, which would mean the second one (and the INTERSECT) is redundant.

Comment: The query is correct as I have written, because if you use only the first SELECT Statement, the result is incorrect

Comment: The query is: Find all years that have a movie that received a rating of 4 or 5, and sort them in increasing order. The resul is 1937-1939-1989-2009. With my query I get the correct result, however if I use just the first SELECT statement I get 1939-1937-1981-1981-1937-2009 that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just using the `INTERSECT` statement to remove duplicates. There's a much much easier way to do that, which is `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM Movie, Rating
WHERE Movie.mID=Rating.mID AND (stars='4' OR stars='5')
ORDER BY year ASC
```

If this isn't working, try expressing the join directly instead of in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year
FROM Movie NATURAL JOIN Rating ON mID
WHERE (stars='4' OR stars='5')
ORDER BY year ASC
```

Also, make sure the data type for `stars` is not numeric, if it's an integer instead of a string you'll need to remove the quotes around `4` and `5`.

Comment: Ok, but if I use this query in MySQL the column year is empty. Can I have some advices to translate in MySQL???

Comment: What happens in MySQL without the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Is still empty, I think that is necessary use JOIN but I don't understand how to use it

Comment: There's absolutely no need for a JOIN here - are you getting any data at all from MySQL?

Comment: I have insert the same tables on SQLite and MySQL

Comment: Do you get any data shown in MySQL, if you run `SELECT * FROM Movie`?

Comment: If I run SELECT * FROM Movie on MySQL I see the correct Table Movie. The same if I run SELECT * FROM Rating I see the correct Table Rating. Seem that don't run "WHERE Movie.mID=Rating.mID AND (stars='4' OR stars='5')".

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM rating WHERE stars = 4` returns rows?

Comment: Run "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE stars = 4" return rows.

Comment: Try the first syntax, but without the quotes around the `4` and `5`.

Comment: No it doesn't work, seem that don't work Movie.mID=Rating.mID

Comment: Are the `mID` values populated appropriately in both tables?